# Deleting spaces in DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have two TextBoxes, one ComboBox and one DataGridView in my program
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWUS8.jpg) The button code is like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tablo1.Clear();
MySqlConnection baglanti = new MySqlConnection("Server=**.***.***.** ;Port=3306 ;Database =*** ;Uid=*** ;Pwd='****' ;");
baglanti.Open();
string kommand = "Select * from ecz";
MySqlDataAdapter daa = new MySqlDataAdapter(kommand, baglanti);

daa.Fill(tablo1);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo1;
baglanti.Close();
tablo1.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text, comboBox2.SelectedItem, textBox1.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo1;
}
```

When I click the button, the table in the database comes to DataGridView. Next, the values in the ComboBox and TextBox are added to the DataGridView. But there is a blank line between them [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJWgi.jpg) I made my code to remove that empty line.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
tablo1.Clear();
MySqlConnection baglanti = new MySqlConnection("Server=**.***.***.** ;Port=3306 ;Database =*** ;Uid=*** ;Pwd='***' ;");
baglanti.Open();
string kommand = "Select * from ecz";
MySqlDataAdapter daa = new MySqlDataAdapter(kommand, baglanti);

daa.Fill(tablo1);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo1;
baglanti.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
string allo = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
if ( allo== "")
{
  dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index);
}
}
 tablo1.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text, comboBox2.SelectedItem, textBox1.Text);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = tablo1;
}
```

However, when I change the code in this way, I can not make consecutive additions to the DataGridView.
All additions are added to the last row in the DataGridView.
I want to add the line to the DataGridView without spaces. But I want to be able to make additions in a row.Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you have this empty line in your database table named _ecz_. Can you check?

Comment: can you not call the `.Trim()` method on the fields or do that on the database end where you are doing your Select Statement..? you would then need to specify the Trim(FieldNames) as Field Name Aliasing. I would start with the simplest place to eliminate having to write extra code on the backend..